# Is it possible to customize the Email stylesheet of DOCUSIGN

Tags: docusignapi

I am new to docusign and currently exploring the feature to send email when an envelope created for a template.

I can see "Docusign" allows the user to customize the content of EMAIL by updating the email resource.

however my question is, Is it possible to update the [[stylesheet]] placeholder globally so that i can customize the width of the email message etc..

Appreciate your time reading this.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to customize the styles used for producing Emails.

You ***can*** access/customize the CSS stylesheet that's used to produce *the application UI* -- for example, you could customize the CSS file to change the appearance of buttons in the DocuSign application for your account.  You can access the application UI's CSS file in the same place that you can access Resource files -- i.e., Preferences >> Branding >> (Edit Brand) >> Resources (tab). (If you don't see it there, DocuSign will have to enable your access to CSS for your account.)

FWIW -- even though it's possible to customize CSS styles used by the application UI, it's an error prone process that's difficult to maintain as DocuSign releases new product versions every few months.  IMO, unless it's an absolute requirement, modifying the CSS file isn't a great idea.

Comment: Ohh. But it looks like an error with regards to the Email CSS. If i give a brand image, the "View Document" Button is not properly aligned in the email body. Rather it is getting reduced to some odd size and not aligned with the email message. That is the reason i wanted to see if i can get to Email stylesheet resource i can correct them accordingly. But thanks for sharing the information about what can be and what cannot be done with regards to styles